# how to count the tabs in files of directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written a code to read the text file and print the total tabs in the file. but i want to read all the files in directory and count tabs in each file and print the result to single output file.how can i do this?

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE='unit-1-slide.txt'
TABCOUNT=$(tr -cd '\t' < $FILE  | wc -c)
echo $TABCOUNT "tabs in file" $FILE >> output.txt
echo "Done!"
```

Comment: `/bin/sh` is the bourne shell, not bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to loop over all the files like:

```
#!/bin/bash    

for file in *; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        tabs=$(tr -cd '\t' < "$file"  | wc -c);
        echo "$tabs tabs in file $file" >> output
    fi
done
```

The file output will look like this after running:

```
8 tabs in file file1
4 tabs in file file2
0 tabs in file file3
3 tabs in file file4
...
```

Notes:

You should always quote your variables to handle filenames with special characters like spaces and it's a good idea to check if it's a file and not a directory also.